# How to select one (or multi) particular particle hair?

Tags: particles, hair, select

[image: hair]
As you can see,I am in particle edit point mode. If I use select box tool on the left,I can left click drag my mouse creating a rectangle,when I leave my mouse,the points in the rectangle is selected. However,if there is many hair in the mesh,it will be very difficult to select one (or multi) particular complete hair in this way.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about your setup and clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok,I 'll put some pictures.

Comment: In the description,I have to press ctrl and use the box many times to select a complete hair,In maya or 3ds max they can simply click or drag a region to select complete hair.

Comment: Hi there :) . In edit mode you can select one strand of hair as you call it by hovering your pointer over it and clicking L. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Nxdhin2005  Thanks,that solves my problem.

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 You can answer in the answer section actually- -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select an object in edit mode you can hover your pointer over the object you wanna select and press <kbd>L</kbd> which will select the entire object you want and ignore the other objects within the edit mode

Comment: Is it possible to have a box selection for complete hair or change selected points to complete hair?

Comment: Hi! You can not 'click' a key on the keyboard. Also always consider adding a link to the manual and include the proper hotkey markup: `<kbd>L</kbd>` so we do not have to edit all of your posts, thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry @brockmann I never knew about  those I will edit it right now.

Comment: @Michael white are you asking about selecting the entire hair in edit mode if so just press A

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 I mean selecting some  hair not the entire hair.For example,there is 10 hair in total,I want to select 8 of them, if I have selected 2 keys on separate hair,can I change the selection to 2 hair ?

Comment: Oh for that select the two hairs that you don't want and press ctrl + i to invert the selection. ctrl + I to invert selection to the other two hairs...

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 Thanks again,you're really helpful.